# Are the members in the statement with AND operator always checked in the given order?

Tags: delphi, logical-operators

I would like to know if the following code may ever fail with the access violation or if it's safe. Is the first member of the statement with AND operator always checked as first or may be (by some compiler optimization or something) checked the second one as first ?

```
var
  Item: TSomething;

procedure DoSomething;
begin
  if Assigned(Item) and (Item.SomeProperty) then
    DoSomethingElse;
end;
```

Is the code above definitely safe ?

Thanks!

Comment: `and` is an operator, not a statement. Your example can throw null pointer exception `$IFOPT B+`

Comment: @user539484, sorry for my weak terminology :) I thought it's the statement with `and` operator. I'll fix it. Thanks for the clear answer hidden in your comment.

Comment: why not
`if assigned(item) then
if item.someproperty then`

Comment: @PieterB, I know it would be even more readable, but it's just because curiosity and because I'm lazy :-)

Comment: @MartinReiner, it OK :-) I'm pedantic on this matter because many years ago translators of programming literature to my native language developed an ugly tradition to denote *statement* and *operator* by the same word. In Pascal it was more or less endurable, thank Wirth, but in C it made whole devastating mess. Thats why

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code is safe given [boolean short-circuit evaluation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Boolean_short-circuit_evaluation_%28Delphi_compiler_directive%29) is active:

> In the {$B-} state, the compiler generates code for short-circuit Boolean expression evaluation, which means that evaluation stops as soon as the result of the entire expression becomes evident in left to right order of evaluation.

It is a bit confusing as the `B` (or `BOOLEVAL` with long name) directive must be turned OFF to switch short-circuit evaluation ON...

See also [Operator Precedence](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Expressions_%28Delphi%29#Operator_Precedence).

Comment: This directive should never have seen the light at all. Who on earth wants "full" boolean evaluation?

Comment: I guess the short-circuit expression evaluation was added later, as a optimization, and in order to not break existing code which depended on full evaluation, the compiler directive was created.

Comment: In my experience (learn by hard way), if the Item.SomeProperty is variant type, it will be evaluated and can cause AV.  However, so many people upvote the answer make me confused....

Comment: @ain & Ulrich. I think short-circuit evaluation has always been default, hence the inclusion of the directive to turn it off, not the other way round. There are some cases where it's useful; I have used it exactly once in some error-checking code that instead of borking on finding the first error, finds all the errors, and informs the user. With short-circuit evaluation enabled the code to do that would be less readable.

Comment: Hmm, i see double negation there. In B- state *short-circuit evaluation* is **enabled**, while in B+ state *complete evaluation* is enabled.

Comment: You should mention that short-circuit boolean evaluation {$B-} is the default setting. The switch was introduced in turbo pascal 5.0

Comment: @User, you can remove the double-negation by referring to the feature as *complete Boolean evaluation*, as it was at least as recently as Delphi 2007. In `$B+` mode, it's on, and in `$B-` mode, it's off.

Comment: @RobKennedy, yup, i believe (cannot prove) thats a canonical name of directive and codegen feature. However you are incorrect about D2007, it yet named "short-circuit" there. Same is for D7. I cant go any deeper...

Comment: From the turbo pascal 5 reference guide: Boolean Evaluation switches between the two different models of code generation for the **and** and **or** Boolean operators. In the {$B+} state, the compiler generates code for complete Boolean expression evaluation. <snip> In the {$B-} state, the compiler generates code for short-circuit Boolean expression evaluation.

Comment: @User, in any picture of the compiler-options dialog box I can find on Google, the option is labeled "complete boolean eval." It's hard to tell what version of the dialog I'm looking at most of the time, though.

Comment: @RobKennedy, ah, i got your point, you are talking about dialog box, i was looking into documentation. Most ancient one i have is for D7, where preferred state - short-circuit - has been moved into the title, and hence is that my remark about double negation there.

Comment: @LURD, wow, such an antique manual you have, i'm impressed :-)

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your Item.SomeProperty type.  If it is Variant, or if there is a variant to be evaluated before it, it will be evaluated and cause AV.

Edit : Forget to mention the workaround :
If the SomeProperty is Variant type, you can use

```
  if Assigned(Item) and StrToBool(Item.SomeProperty) then
```

It do spend some time to convert the variable to String then back to boolean but at lease it can satisfy all cases of being true / false / non-existence.

Below is a test case for you to see :

```
unit Unit4;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Generics.Collections;

type
  TTestObj = class
  public
    V : Variant;
    I : Integer;
  end;

  TForm4 = class(TForm)
    btn1: TButton;
    btn2: TButton;
    btn3: TButton;
    procedure btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btn3Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    TOV : TTestObj;
  end;

var
  Form4: TForm4;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm4.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(TOV) and (TOV.I = 10) then
    ShowMessage('You will never see this though no AV!');
end;

procedure TForm4.btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(TOV) and StrToBool(TOV.V) then
    ShowMessage('You will not see AV with StrToBool!');
  if Assigned(TOV) and TOV.V then
    ShowMessage('You will never see this but AVed!');
end;

procedure TForm4.btn3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  V : Variant;
begin
  V := False;
  if Assigned(TOV) and V and (TOV.I = 10) then
    ShowMessage('You will see AV!');
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thanks for this very important note! The members are luckily not Variant typed.

Comment: @MartinReiner Even the member is not Variant, also careful if there is any Variant type in the expression.  If Assigned(TOV) and V and (TOV.I = 10) then... where V is variant will also cause TOV.I to be evaluated and cause AV.  I will update the answer to show that.

Comment: Interesting, i didn't know about that

Comment: @user539484 I guess the logic is 1. If there is variant, it start evaluate the expression from right to left to resolve variable type, when type issue is resolved, it evaluate from left to right and quit evaluating when result is ensured.  So, "if Assigned(TOV) and V and (TOV.I = 10) then" generate AV while "if Assigned(TOV) and (TOV.I = 10) and V then" do not.

Comment: This appears to be reasonable hypothesis. Good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Its safe to Call the condition you mentioned 
Have a look

I have a stringlist and I checked for the two conditions

```
    Strinlst : TStringlist; 

      Tester.pas.169: if ( (Assigned(Strinlst)) and(Strinlst.count<>6)) then
      0052A3CC 8BB3E4030000     mov esi,[ebx+$000003e4]
      0052A3D2 85F6             test esi,esi              //check if Strinlst is assigned
      0052A3D4 741F             jz $0052a3f5              //jump out if not true 
      0052A3D6 8BC6             mov eax,esi
      0052A3D8 8B10             mov edx,[eax]
      0052A3DA FF5214           call dword ptr [edx+$14]
      0052A3DD 83F806           cmp eax,$06               //compare the count
      0052A3E0 7413             jz $0052a3f5              //jump to the result
```

Same goes for the condition in other order

```
      Tester.pas.169: if ( (Strinlst.count<>6) and (Assigned(Strinlst)) ) then
      0052A3CB 8B83E4030000     mov eax,[ebx+$000003e4]
      0052A3D1 8B10             mov edx,[eax]
      0052A3D3 FF5214           call dword ptr [edx+$14]   //get the count
      0052A3D6 83F806           cmp eax,$06                //compare the count    
      0052A3D9 741B             jz $0052a3f6               //jump if not true  
      0052A3DB 83BBE403000000   cmp dword ptr [ebx+$000003e4],$00 //compare if Strinlst is assigned
      0052A3E2 7412             jz $0052a3f6              //jump if false
```

so certainly the order of conditions is followed from Left to Right